# public variable not accessible

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

In one namespace (Ventosa.Graphics) I have a public class named Model

```
namespace Ventosa.Graphics
{
   public class Model : GraphicsResource
   {
       public Model(...)
       {
           ...
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

Then in another project I try to access this class

```
Model player = new Model(...);
```

But this line creates an error. C# recognizes that Model exists, but claims that it isn't accessible due to it's protection level. Shouldn't making it public mean it's accessible from everywhere?

And yes, the base class GraphicsResource is public.

This happens in a few other places in my project too, all with classes that are derived.

EDIT:
The exact error message is (in German):
*Der Zugriff auf "Ventosa.Graphics.Model" ist aufgrund der Sicherheitsebene nicht möglich.* Translated to English, it says: *"Ventosa.Graphics.Model" is inaccessible due to its protection level.*

Comment: Are you sure it knows which `Model` class you're talking about? Do you have `using Ventosa.Graphics;` in the class which is trying to use it?

Comment: Are you sure another  Model class doesn't exist is any other namespace? Try changing it to Ventosa.Graphics.Model player = new Ventosa.Graphics.Model() and see...

Comment: Yes, I've double checked that there is no ambiguity anywhere, and yeah, I do have the using statement. I'm pretty confused right now.

Comment: is GraphicResource's constructor public? you need to cut'n'paste the error message as it appears in the Visual Studio output window so people can help you out

Comment: I just tried Ventosa.Graphics.Model, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, GraphicResource's constructor is public too. But it even complains when I declare *Model model;*

Comment: @Hannesh: Mb you referenced old dll where Model class without 'public' modifier? You can check class modifier using reflector.

Comment: Is that really the error you get if the visibility is too low? Shouldn't it complain about too low visibility and not security? Or is the German version just localized that badly?

Comment: And I recommend using English IDEs for everybody that understands English. Localized IDEs cause more annoyances than they are worth.

Comment: ...and it's much easier to search the Internet for English error messages.

Comment: You can use error codes to search, but yes that's one of the reasons. Another is that sometimes the English message contains words which correspond to the keywords of the programming language, but since they are not directly used as keywords they get localized. And I remember the German Delphi help with horror. It didn't contain many keywords in the index and had only the translated word in the index, which I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe something that clearly should not be. I'd suggest that you try to reproduce the problem in the simplest way possible. You probably won't be able to. Then add to your sample, making it more and more like your production code, until you trigger the problem.

Remove the reference to the superclass `GraphicResource`. Make sure there's only one constructor defined. Try to instantiate that class from the same namespace, using full namespace references (*not* `using` statements) and that single, explicit constructor. It'll probably work.

If it doesn't work, step back a bit and define a new type entirely (`Ventosa.Graphics.ModelTest` or something). Make sure *that* works.

Now, add pieces back in. Inherit from `GraphicResource`, try that. Remove the namespace qualifications; use `using` instead. Move the instantiation to a different namespace, then a different assembly.

You've verified that the definition of the `GraphicResource` class is public. What about any of **its** superclasses?

Comment: Any issues with the protection level of a BaseClass would surface when compiling the Model class.

Comment: I took your advice and made a new type. It worked fine, so I just copied the code over and renamed the new class. The reason it didn't work before still escapes me, but now I can move on with my project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound silly, but have tried to restart Visual Studio (after Cleaning and Rebuilding the solution)? I noticed some strange behavior, especially if you have Code-Coverage enabled and some of the Powertools for Visual Studio installed.

Was Model internal in some previous builds? It's a really common name.

Edit: A way to make sure you actually have the right type, you can hover the "Model" declaration in your second project and press F12 (or right click and choose "Go To Definition", don't know the german term right now). This should take you to your class or to the definition of some other "Model"-class (.NET internal types are displayed too).

Comment: Yes, model was internal in previous builds, and this is most likely the problem. This has been frustrating me for days now, in between which my computer has been restarted multiple times.

Comment: Did you try to delete all compiler generated DLLs (bin/Debug, bin/Release in all projects)? If you have deployment enabled for Unit-Tests you could clear/remove the TestResults folder. Also remove the .suo file (located in the same directory as your .sln, but have to use `attrib -h *.suo` to actually see it), the information in it are regenerated on the next build.